# How do I backup my customer's data?

Tags: backups

If you run a SaaS app, or work on one, I would love to hear from you. Where the safety and security of your customer's data is paramount, how do you secure it and back it up? I would love to know your main host (e.g. Heroku, Engine Yard, Rackspace, MediaTemple, etc.) and who you use for your backup.

Be as detailed as possible - e.g. a quick overview of your service and the data you store (images for instance), what happens with the images when the user uploads them (e.g. they go to your Linode VPS, and posted to the site for them to see - then they are automatically sent to AWS or wherever, then once a week they are backed up to tape by the managed hosting provider, and you also back them up to your house/office).

If you could also give some idea as to what the unit cost (per GB/per user/per month) of storage is - on average, I would really appreciate that.

Getting ready to launch my app, and I would love to get some more perspective on the nitty gritty details involved.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be on-topic for this site. I think you want [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

I backup my client's websites and database dumps incrementally from production servers to a backup server using rsnapshot. This gives me daily, weekly, and monthly backup sets that are very simple to restore without huge amounts of wasted space.

I then use duplicity to created compressed, encrypted backups of the latest daily rsnapshot backups, and use rsync to transfer these to the Rackspace cloud using Jungledisk. As I'm only dealing with a few GB's of data, the cost is next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

consider a service like S3 where there is redundancy at a backup level.

Also, as your customer's data is critical, its best you encrypt your data before storing it anywhere outside your vicinity.